# Why does Davos go with Jon?

Tags: game-of-thrones

From reading [Why did Jon Snow choose someone he barely knew to this post?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77905/why-did-jon-snow-make-this-choice), over at **Movies and TV**, I came to realise that Ser Davos is Jon's Hand. If that is the case why would Jon leave Sansa in charge and take Davos with him when:

> He goes to meet with Daenerys.

Surely it makes more sense to leave Davos in charge, or at least leave Davos to oversee Sansa.

As it stands, it looks like Littlefinger is going to use this to his advantage to manipulate Sansa into what he wants from her and that doesn't look like a sensible thing for Jon to have done.

Comment: To keep winterfell in the hands of a stark. Jon is not very clever :)

Comment: @Philipp I understand that part, but why wouldn't he leave Davos to oversee what Sansa is doing? He can go without both of them, he doesn't need both to go with him.

Comment: @Philipp And I wouldn't say that, he does what he thinks is right, as his "father" would have done.

Comment: It would be insulting to Sansa, "you have command, but Davos will watch over your actions so you don't do stupid things". Just my opinion tho

Comment: So he has his hand with him when he's discussing important matters

Comment: @Philipp Jon has command but he has advisers that make sure he doesn't do anything stupid as does Daenerys and all the other leaders. It's not insulting it's what makes sense.

Comment: @Edlothiad I know there's a toss up with that one but keeping control of the North and ruling it are also important matters.

Comment: Looks to me like Sansa is going to use this to her advantage to manipulate Littlefinger into what she wants from him, but hey, what do I know?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite In my opinion Sansa has been all talk and is scared to actually have the responsibility now. Littlefinger is known to manipulate people for what he wants and obviously has an interest in her. Both of those points is why I believe it is the other way around.

Comment: Because Davos meeting Melisandre will be great drama

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: manipulation generally involves a bit of talking. And Sansa was at least capable of predicting and resisting Ramsay’s attempted manipulation using Rickon, unlike Jon.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I agree she's gotten better at resisting it but Littlefinger is a master of it remember.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: meh. Who has he really manipulated? Aunt Lysa? Everyone else he’s pretty much just got stuff from them in return for genuine help; he just happened to be helping their enemies at the same time. I don’t think Sansa’s under any illusions about the likelihood of him instantly switching back to Team Lannister if that becomes a more attractive option.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think he's more of a hands in the background manipulator. More implied that he's always doing it than showing but I agree that there are few examples to go on.

Comment: Because Davos has to announce Jon as "Jon Snow, Lord Commander of the Nights Watch, Lord of Winterfell, (king/warden) of the North, Slayer of White Walkers and Protector of the Free Folk, the White Wolf, the Resurrected..." when he meets the Dragon Queen

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Davos is important to the journey not just as a an advisor but because of his knowledge and experience

Davos might be Jon's Hand or counceler but more importantly he knows Dragonstone, how to get there, its geography and, as Bailey points in his comment, is an acomplished seaman and smuggler.

Given that Jon's travel primary objective is stopping the white walkers army, and getting Dragonglass is one of the ways to accomplish that, counting with Davos in the journey is a great asset.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that aspect; I was mainly focusing on the leadership part. Good answer.

Comment: Additionally, Davos is a very skilled seaman who, as a smuggler, is particularly skilled in fast stealth sailing.  I haven't seen John with a kingsguard and we know there is at least one unfriendly fleet (Euron) out there who would be happy to capture a priceless gift such as Jon.

Also, Davos made a number of similar trips while serving Stannis.  He would frequently travel to various lord's and lady's castles to ask for assistance.  He probably learned a few things in those trips.

Comment: @ABailey: good point: Sir Davos actually knows how to sail. For all we know, Jon can’t even swim — I’m gonna guess that Northerners in Westeros don’t take a lot of beach holidays.

Answer (score 2):

### Ser Davos has no ties to The North, only to Jon

It is not explained *exactly* what it is that ties Ser Davos to Jon Snow, but he definitely seems to admire him, as a leader and also as a person.

When Jon brought him along to Winterfell, won the Battle of the Bastards and was named King in The North, **he didn't actually proclaim Davos as his Hand**, or any other official position. So there's no reason for any of the Northern lords to follow Davos.

### There must always be a Stark in Winterfell

What, like name a random southerner, up-jumped to his position by a 'traitor King' to rule over Winterfell and the North over a Stark? No way, there's no chance that the Northern Lords and Ladies would have that, no matter how much they support Jon.

### The true war is coming

Additionally, when Ser Davos read the letter which was sent by Lord Commander Mormont asking for assistance against the impending doom of the White Walkers, he was instantly inspired, even convincing Stannis to take up that cause as well. This is Davos' primary objective, and going to Dragonstone to get obsidian and perhaps even the dragons themselves serves this purpose.

### Even if he were the Hand

Remember when Jon announces that he must go to see Daenerys, and Sansa says:

> Then send an emissary, don't go yourself

Jon replies:

> Daenerys is a Queen, only a King can convince her to help us

What he's saying is that he needs as much power and authority backing him as possible, it would stand to reason that he would take his supposed Hand. Besides, Dany has her Hand next to her, why not Jon?

Answer (score -1):

Well, the out of universe explanation is that Jon can't go to Dragonstone on his own.

There need to be two people at least on either side to have an interesting conversation that the viewers can watch. There's no other proper character that we know well in Winterfell who Jon can trust. Story wise it makes sense. In the real world not really.

Comment: Very opinion based.